# Java - How to prove Set is using Map as the internal data structure to store the elements?

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, set

I came to know that java Set uses map as the internal data structure to store the elements . But I want to prove this. how can I prove?

https://www.javatpoint.com/q/7105/what-is-the-data-structure-that-a-set-uses-to-store-its-elements?

Comment: Show them source code.

Comment: How did you come to know that?

Comment: Note that `Set` is an interface.. (for the source code, see http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/HashSet.java/ for example)

Comment: Sorry I am not able to understand the source . Do we have example source for this?

Comment: For example, you could check the source code for [HashSet](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/HashSet.java#HashSet). In the constructor it creates a new HashMap instance.

Comment: Ok . Is there any specific reason for this . I mean , using the map implementation for Set?

Comment: Convenience, the code already exists

Answer (score 0):

I doubt very much that it is true for all implementations of `interface Set`.

The way I found out that it is true for HashSet was that I inspected a `HashSet` object in eclipse.

This should work for you to show it to your colleges. For more of a proof, look at the source linked by @RC.

Comment: Indeed, `EnumSet` is not implemented using a `Map`.